# Склонение слова "интернет"

Tags: склонение

Одна школьница жаловалась, что их учительница русского языка настаивает на том, что слово "интернет" не склоняется. Честно говоря, у меня большие сомнения на этот счет, но, может, я не права?

Comment: Конечно же склоняется. И даже во множественном числе: http://lurkmore.to/интернеты

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать аргументы учительницы на этот счет

Answer (score 7):

Вы правы! Слово Интернет склоняется. Интернет, интернета, интернету и т.д. Конечно, если вы будете  употреблять его в качестве приложения, то склонять не надо: в сети Интернет. Но, по-моему, такое употребление устаревает.